# Swift UI - How to make Image Grids?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Need to create a grid of images with SwiftUI, that dynamically change rows according to screen width.

When I use `List`, I can only get one column..

I tried Hstacks to make 2 columns, but then it doesn't work dynamically for screen width.

Ex: iPhone portrait should have 1 column 
Ex: iPhone landscape  should have 2 column

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductGrid : View {
    var body: some View {

        List(0 ..< 5) { item in

            VStack() {
                Image("product")
                HStack {

                   ProfileImageSmall()
                        VStack {
                            Text("Product")

                            Text("Username")


                        }


                    }



            }

        }
    }
}
```

How can I make a grid that column count adapts to screen width?

Comment: For now, you can't. That is, unless you use `UIKit` - which I honestly do not know if it's possible there.

Comment: Could you post a sketch of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @dfd if what he's after is something like what the Photos app does, obviously it is possible.

Comment: Does Photos use SwiftUI? A solution of “wrap a UIKit view in a `UIViewRepresentable`” might be the only answer right now, but it's not exactly a *good* answer.

Comment: Which is why I posted a pretty vague comment. Using `HStack` and `VStack`, even a `List` won't do it. And again, as @matt indicates, what are the limitations in iOS 13 Photos? Does it use SwiftUI? UIKit? Best guess on my part is that **if** the new Photos app (really haven't played with it yet in iOS 13) handles what is needed **and** is not part of iOS 12, then it likely uses SwiftUI. BUT... is this something available in SwiftUI beta 1? I'm pretty sure there's many "not ready for prime time, less beta" features Apple is using.

Comment: @robmayoff Oh, no, I don't think it does. dfd said he didn't know if was possible _in UIKit_. I'm saying that it obviously is, since Photos has been making an adaptable grid for years. Assuming, of course, that that's what the OP is describing...

Answer (score 5):

Available for **XCode 12**

```
import SwiftUI

//MARK: - Adaptive
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum:100))]) {
                ForEach(yourObjects) { object in
                    YourObjectView(item: object)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Custom Columns
struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
         ScrollView {   
             LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 4)) {
                 ForEach(yourObjects) { object in
                     YourObjectView(item: object)
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Don't forget replace the info **objects** with your info and **YourObjectView** with your **customView**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use size classes to determine the right interface orientation.

[image]

To check whether an iPhone is landscape or not, you can check the vertical size class environment value.

When the device is `portrait`, it is set to `.regular`, otherwise it returns `.compact`.

You can use `@Environment` property wrapper to subscribe to that environment value, and have the view redraw itself when a change occur.

In this example, I have a large green square displayed when the iPhone is in `portrait` mode, and two smaller squares (one green, one pink) when the iPhone is in `landscape` mode.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(1...24) { item in
                    if self.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer(minLength: geometry.size.width * 0.15)
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.70,
                                       height: geometry.size.height * 0.3)
                            Spacer(minLength: geometry.size.width * 0.15)
                        }
                    } else {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer(minLength: geometry.size.width * 0.05)
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.40,
                                       height: geometry.size.height)
                            Spacer(minLength: geometry.size.width * 0.05)
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(.pink)
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.40,
                                       height: geometry.size.height)
                            Spacer(minLength: geometry.size.width * 0.05)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Portrait layout**:

[image]

**Landscape layout**:

[image]

Comment: "The environment horizontalSizeClass changes when the interface rotates" Not on an iPad.

Comment: Thanks again Matteo! But unfortunately as @matt mentioned this won't work for iPad. There should be some kind of "grid system" in SwiftUI that handles this kind of situation?

Comment: Another thread about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466306/uicollectionview-and-swiftui

Comment: @AlexandreLordelo you could provide a bespoke layout for iPad  if `horizontalSizeClass == .regular && verticalSizeClass == .regular`?