# I want to make a view in which I can add x number or buttons

Tags: list, uicollectionview, swiftui, hstack

I am trying to add buttons to a dynamic view. What I am trying to achieve us that I have an array and I want to create a list of buttons and want to fill that list horizontally first and when there is no space in screen next button should appear in next line and so on. I am proving an image for more understanding.[Something like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bn19.jpg)

I don't want to create a for list of loop for x number or text fields in Hstack. I am trying to achieve a dynamic width of button, one row may have 2 number of buttons and another may have 4 (according to length of text)

I already tried following code

```
var body: some View {
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack {
        ForEach(1...3) {_ in
            HStack {
                Color.orange.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                Color.orange.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                Color.orange.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 100)
        }
    }
}}
```

I already checked few answers but I am unable to find proper answer. If there is any proper answer there please provide a link before marking this question as duplicate.

Comment: That seems like a `UICollectionView`. There should be an equivalent of it in SwiftUI.

Comment: can't find any. I also want dynamic width for these buttons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466306/uicollectionview-and-swiftui

Comment: please check edited question