# How can I make my SwiftUI grid view work?

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I am trying to make a grid view in SwiftUI, composed of a varying amount of view elements. I used this thread as an orientation: [UICollectionView and SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466306/uicollectionview-and-swiftui)

I have an collection that holds my elements, chunked into snippets of 3 each:

```
let test = allTheRewards.filter({ !$0.completed }).chunked(into: 3)
```

Then, in my "mother view", I'm iterating through them like this to pass the data to the child view element:

```
VStack {

                            ForEach(self.test.indices, id:\.self) { idx in

                                HStack {

                                    ForEach(self.test[idx].indices, id:\.self) { index in

                                        HStack {


                                            TestReward(name: self.test[idx][index].name, description: self.test[idx][index].description, shape: self.test[idx][index].shape, bgStart: self.test[idx][index].bgStart, bgEnd: self.test[idx][index].bgEnd, isComplete: self.test[idx][index].completed)


                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }
```

The problem here is that the compiler doesn't seem to like that many uses of the indexes ([idx][index]).

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
>   time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

It works fine when I'm only using it a few times in the call to pass my arguments, but it doesn't work with the current 6 times. The compiling time increases a lot and it eventually fails. So I think this may be a pretty inefficient way to go about it. But I don't know what would be a better solution. Any ideas?

Further info:
It is no problem to use the amount of indexes in separate elements, like this:

```
Text("\(self.uncompletedRewards[idx][index].name)")
Text("\(self.uncompletedRewards[idx][index].description)")
Text("\(self.uncompletedRewards[idx][index].shape)")
Text("\(String(describing: (self.uncompletedRewards[idx][index].bgStart)))")
Text("\(String(describing: (self.uncompletedRewards[idx][index].bgEnd)))")
Text("\(String(self.uncompletedRewards[idx][index].completed))")
```

I just seem not able to put this all into one call...

Answer (score 1):

```
TestReward(model: model, row: row, column: column)
```

or

```
TestReward(row: row, column: column).environmentObject(model)
```

should solve your trouble and dramatically increase readability (and next maintenance) of your codebase.

Comment: Thanks!

I actually created a helper function to pass the data to the view. It also works and is quite fast. But I don't know if it should be done like that....